# Regular Expression - Match a string after '?' and end with '#'

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression, it should match a string after '?' and end with '#'.

Simple Input:
somegarbage?Hello,world#garbage

Simple Output:
Hello,world#

Comment: What have you tried? Which language or tool are you using? What if there are multiple `?` and `#` in the string? Do you want the outermost match? Do you want innermost matches? All of them? The first one?

Comment: Although regular expressions work almost the same on all platforms, there could be a non-regex solution for your problem. Can you specify the language/platform?

Comment: Is this a fragment of a URL that you're trying to match?

Comment: > Is this a fragment of a URL that you're trying to match?
No, I just choose them randomly. I will change them in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<=\?).*#
```

`(?<=\?)` means starting with a `?` but not including it.

Answer (score 0):

with info currently given, thw following should work

```
.*\?(.*#).*
```

the group contains the value in question